# Alternative to NetScanner

Tags: networking, software-recommendation, security

Is there a software alternative to [NetScanner](http://www.softperfect.com/products/networkscanner/) (which runs on the Windows platform)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try `nmap`, it's console based, but you can install `nmapsi4` which is a very easy to use gui.

```
sudo apt-get install nmapsi4
```

This will install both packages.

Comment: Hadn't heard of nmapsi4.  Nice one.  It's QT based, so I'll likely (definitely) prefer zenmap, but I'll have to give it a try sometime.

Comment: @Scain: You are right, if using Ubuntu definitely `zenmap`, I didn't notice that `nmapsi4` was QT based.

Comment: @scaine I haven't played with it much, but nmapsi4 looks very good (well, the competition isn't much -- zenmap and umit are pretty bare bones).  I'll probably keep it on my system, despite being Gnome/gtk-centric at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [zenmap](http://nmap.org/zenmap/), which is the graphical interface to the command-line `nmap`.

```
sudo apt-get install zenmap
```

It's pretty easy to use.  It won't do mapped drive mounting though, although it's got other very useful features like OS detection and non-ping based scans.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned, [nmap](http://packages.ubuntu.com/nmap) [image: Install nmap]
 is probably the way to go.
The front-ends I know about are [zenmap](http://packages.ubuntu.com/zenmap) [image: Install zenmap] , [umit](http://packages.ubuntu.com/umit) [image: Install umit], [nmapsi4](http://packages.ubuntu.com/nmapsi4) [image: Install nmapsi4], and [knmap](http://packages.ubuntu.com/knmap) [image: Install knmap] .

[Sectools.org](http://sectools.org/) has some lists of other software that might be of interest (for various platforms, but of course including Linux).

There are also some more specialized scanning tools in the Ubuntu repositories, such as doscan, pnscan, and [hping3](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hping3) [image: Install hping3]
.

`nmap` is probably the most widely used, though.

Answer (score 2):

[AngryIP](http://www.angryip.org) is a good scanner. It's primarily used through the gui, but has cli options too:

```
jake@daedalus:/$ ipscan --help
Unknown option: -

Pass the following arguments:
[options] <feeder> <exporter>

Where <feeder> is one of:
-f:range <Start IP> <End IP>
-f:random <Base IP> <IP Mask> <Count>
-f:file <File>

<exporter> is one of:
-o filename.txt         Text file (txt)
-o filename.csv         Comma-separated file (csv)
-o filename.xml         XML file (xml)
-o filename.lst         IP:Port list (lst)

And possible [options] are (grouping allowed):
-s      start scanning automatically
-q      quit after exporting the results
-a      append to the file, do not overwrite
```

Comment: Cool - hadn't heard of this one.